# SQL reporting invalid syntax when run in Power BI

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

I have written an SQL script which runs fine when executed directly in SQL Management Studio. However, when entering it into Power BI as a source, it reports that it has an incorrect syntax.

This is the query:

```
            EXEC "dbo"."p_get_bank_balance" '2'
```

However, the syntax is apparently incorrect? See Picture:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT ***

When the double quotes are removed (as per Tab Alleman's suggestion):

[image]

Comment: I suspect it's the quoted identifier.   Try [dbo].[p_get_bank_balance]

Comment: Hi @TabAlleman, I tried your suggestion, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: To be clear, you removed the quotes from around the schema and table names?   Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Hi @TabAlleman, I have added the screenshot to the question

Comment: Well that's what I would have tried.  I'm out of ideas, it's got to be a Power BI quirk, and I don't have Power BI to play with.   I have added the Power BI tag to your question to hopefully attract experts in that tool.  One more thing you could try is start a Profiler trace and see what code Power BI attempts to execute when you run that line.

Comment: Pass the parameter name (@P = 2 )!! does parameter is string or Int? `EXEC "dbo"."p_get_bank_balance" @prametername = 2`

Comment: still getting the same error @Hiten004, the '2' is for the value Bank_ID. I have tried the query with '@bank_id = 2 and it does work, just not in Power BI.

Comment: You can use OPENQUERY to "select" from stored procedures: select * from openquery([ServerName],  'Database.dbo.p_get_bank_balance ''param1'', ''param2''')

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found time ago the same problem online on power bi site:

http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Use-SQL-Store-Procedure-in-Power-BI/td-p/20269

> You must be using DirectQuery mode, in which you cannot connect to data with stored procedures.  Try again using Import mode or just use a SELECT statement directly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Have a look at this article: [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

In DirectQuery mode, PowerBI automatically wraps your query like so: `select * from ( [your query] )`, and if you attempt this in SSMS with a stored procedure i.e.

```
select * from (exec dbo.getData)
```

You get the error you see above.

The solution is you have to place your stored procedure call in an OPENQUERY call to your local server i.e.

```
select * from OPENQUERY(localServer, 'DatabaseName.dbo.getData')
```

Prerequisites would be: enabling local server access in OPENQUERY with

```
exec sp_serveroption @server = 'YourServerName' 
   ,@optname = 'DATA ACCESS' 
   ,@optvalue = 'TRUE'
```

And then making sure you use three-part notation in the OPENQUERY as all calls there default to the `master` database

Answer (score 0):

With "Import" data connectivity mode Stored Procedures work
With "Direct Query" data connectivity mode, the query syntax must be like below:

declare @sqlCommand varchar(100) = 'dbo.p_get_bank_balance'
declare @p1 int = 2

exec @sqlCommand @p1 = @p1

Remerber: max one data source connection with Direct Query. If you want to call much SP, only one can be in Direct Query mode, the others in Import mode

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Import** instead of Direct Query. It may be showing error cause you are using Temp table in it. Create query using sub query and remove Temp table and try it. Or you can **use as Import instead of Direct Query** it will work.